# passing multidimensional array as argument in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

C newbie here, I need some help: Can anyone explain to (and offer a workaroud) me why this works:

```
int n=1024;
int32_t data[n];
void synthesize_signal(int32_t *data) {
       ...//do something with data}
```

which let me alter data in the function; but this does not?

```
int n=1024;
int number=1024*16;
int32_t data[n][2][number];
void synthesize_signal(int32_t *data) {
       ...//do something with data}
```

The compiler error message is something like it expected `int32_t *` but got `int32_t (*)[2][(sizetype)(number)]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, passing arrays in C is by reference. So you pass a pointer of some sort, and the function can modify the data in the array. You don't have to worry about passing a pointer to the array. In fact, in C there is no real different between a pointer that happens to be to the being of an array, and the array itself.

In your first version. You making a one-dimensional array data[n], and you are passing it to your function. In the array, you'll using it by saying, something like data[i]. This translates directly to *(data + (i* sizeof(int32_t)). It is using the size of the elements in the array to find the memory location that is i positions in front of the beginning of your array.

int n=1024;
int number=1024*16;
int32_t data[n][2][number];
void synthesize_signal(int32_t *data)

In the second case, you're setting up a mufti-dimensional array (3D in your case). You setup correctly. The problem is that when you pass it to the function, the only thing that gets passed the address of the being of the array. When it gets used inside the function, you'll do something like

```
data[i][1][x] = 5;
```

Internally C is calculating how from the beginning of the array this location is. In order for it to do that, it need to know the dimensions of the array. (Unlike some newer languages, C store any extra data about array lengths or sizes or anything). You just need to change the function signature so it knows the shape/size of array to expect. Because of the way, it calculates array positions, it doesn't need the first dimension.

In this case, change your function signature to look like this:

```
void synthesize_signal(int32_t data[][2][number]) { ...
```

Setup the array the same way you are doing the second one above, and just call it you'd expect:

```
synthesize_signal(data);
```

This should fix everything for you.

The comments mention some useful information about using more descriptive variable names, and global vs. local variable. All valid comments to keep in mind. I just addressed to code problem you're having in terms of mufti-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I do this if I don't now `number` beforehand? Can I pass it as an argument too?

Comment: @wa4557 The code inside the function needs to know dimensions of the array to access it. Given a one-dimensional array of ints, you can work with it as if it was whatever shape you want, but you will have to coerce it into that shape and/or do the offset calculations yourself. In order to do that you'll to know the dimensions though, so you haven't really gotten anywhere. 

If you need more flexibility, it is often easier to change the way you're working with the data. For example using a 1d array of structs. It is really of matter of what you are doing with the data and the context.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
synthesize_signal(int32_t** data)
{

}
```

Your function also needs to know that data is multi dimensional. You should also consider renaming your data array. I suspect that it is a global variable and using the same name in function can lead to problems.

Comment: Nope, now it complains that it is expecting a `int32_t **` but got a `int32_t (*)[2][(sizetype)(number)]` instead

Comment: @Eric, no, you need `void synthesize_signal(int32_t (*data)[2][number])`

Comment: oh I didn't see the 3rd dimension

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function, do it like this:

```
synthesize_signal(&data[0][0][0]);
```